# Ignore Specific ASG Tag Using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, tagging

I am creating ASG resources with terraform and adding tags using the latest syntax such as

```
    tag {
      key                 = "external-sync"
      value               = "false"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }

    tag {
      key                 = "test"
      value               = "false"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    }
```

I need to be able to ignore any changes to the “external-sync” tag after its initial creation as another tool is interacting with that tag in AWS.

I can’t seem to get the syntax right in my ignore block.

I have tried tag["external-sync] but it throws a validation error.

> “Block type “tag” is represented by a set of objects, and set elements do not have addressable keys. To find elements matching specific criteria, use a “for” expression with an “if” clause”

For loop syntax doesn’t work in an ignore_change =  [] block

I can’t seem to find a way to make this work. Any pointers ,much appreciated.

I’m using the latest versions of terraform and the AWS provider.

Comment: Please provide actual code fully demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this "lifecycle" block and add "ignore_changes" block within the "lifecycle" block that will contain everything you want to ignore.

This is an example how to igonre this tag "external-sync" on a specific resource

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  availability_zones = ["us-east-1a"]
  desired_capacity   = 1
  max_size           = 1
  min_size           = 1
  .
  .
  .
  tag {
  key                 = "external-sync"
  value               = "false"   
  propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags["external-sync"]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: tags was removed from the v5 of the aws provider so there is no tags variable "This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "tags". Did you mean "tag"?"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).